# Comparing two chrono timepoints with operators

Tags: c++

How do i compare two `chrono` timepoints in `C++20`?  [This link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point/operator_cmp) says that the `>` and `<` operators are deprecated in `C++20` ?

Comment: You get <=> operator instead of ==,!=,<,<=,>,>=

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are deprecated in favour of the [comparisons automatically provided by the implementation of `operator<=>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_comparisons). You can still compare with `<` or `>`, it's just that explicit definitions for these operators is no longer necessary.